# dart angular2 - access map value component in template

Tags: angular, dart

I'd like to know if there is a way to write something like :

```
 <span>{{myObject?.myField['myKey']}}</span>
```

in my template.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `['myKey']` is evaluated even when `myObject` is `null`. This would require `?[]` but that is not supported

```
<span>{{myObject?.myField != null ? myObject.myField['myKey'] : null}}</span>
```

or

```
<span *ngIf="myObject?.myField != null">{{myObject.myField['myKey']}}</span>
```

<strike>Maybe this works as well (don't remember)</strike>

```
<span *ngIf="myObject?.myField">{{myObject.myField['myKey']}}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm switching a lot between TS and Dart recently and get sometimes confused about what works where.